# PostgreSQL - Creating a trigger: function does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, database-trigger

I'm working on a script for school right now and I've encountered a weird error that I can't fix.
So I've got a playlist, tracks and a playlistInput table.
My task is to create a trigger that if I add/delete a track to my playlist, the amountOfTracks variable should be increased/decreased.

So now to the weird error:
I've made a function "playlistInputAdd" which already works when doing "select playlistInputAdd(1,1)".
The thing is that if I create my trigger, it says that this function doesn't exist. I've seen that someone asked the same question but he didn't add the parameters and I actually did.

The playlistInputAdd function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION playlistInputAdd(ID int, Amount int)
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE playlist
    SET amountOfTracks = amountOfTracks + Amount
    WHERE playListID = ID;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The playlistInputAdd_trigger trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER playlistInputAdd_trigger 
AFTER INSERT
ON playlistInput 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE playlistInputAdd(playlistID, 1);
```

The playlistInputDelete_trigger trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER playlistInputDelete_trigger 
AFTER INSERT
ON playlistInput 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE playlistInputAdd(playlistID, 1);
```

The error message:

```
ERROR: function playlistinputadd() does not exist
```

Thank you, in advance!

Comment: A trigger function needs to be declared as `returns trigger`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger functions must be defined with empty argument list and with `RETURNS trigger`. It is the argument list that causes the error you get.

You *can* pass arguments to the function in `CREATE TRIGGER` (even though the argument list has to be empty), but these have to be constants and can be accessed via `TG_ARGV` in the function body.

You don't need to pass the columns of the modified table as arguments: the row being inserted is available in the `NEW` variable in the trigger body.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) for more.